# How to use OpenDDS 3.13 Security

Tags: c++, ssl, data-distribution-service, opendds

Recently I try to use OpenDDS 3.13 Security.
I also followed the OpenDDS security manual and make and build project.
Configure command like this:

```
$./configure --security --xerces --openssl && make
```

Bulid and make project successful but when I run the example which located in DDS_ROOT/tests/DCPS/Messenger have trouble.

I get the following output:

```
$./publisher -DCPSConfigFile rtps_uni.ini
Starting publisher
Starting publisher with 1 args
(26771|139728132269888) ERROR: DomainParticipantImpl::enable, Unable to validate local identity. SecurityException[-1.0]: GUID_UNKNOWN passed in for candidate_participant_guid
(26771|139728132269888) ERROR: DomainParticipantFactoryImpl::create_participant, unable to enable DomainParticipant.
publisher.cpp:103: main() ERROR: create_participant failed!
```

Can I please get some directions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr.Simpson reply my question, he said that use 
`rtps_disc_sec.ini` instead of `rtps_uni.ini`

source is here:
https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/issues/934